# Carousel Desaparecendo ao inserir um Link

Tags: css, carousel, owl-carousel

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema onde estou tentando referenciar um link em um carousel aqui, porém ele está com problemas. Abaixo a imagem como o site é.

[image: Imagem com layout do Site]

Abaixo imagem como ele fica quando eu coloco o link referenciado no NAV.

[image: Imagem do problema]

O template que eu me baseei para construção dele é este: https://www.myresponsee.com/onepage/

Estou estudando Front-End agora e estava tudo indo certo até ai. haha

Código do Header que apresenta problema. Eu consegui notar que ele não consegue ativar  o 
  .owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    display: block; } quando eu coloco o link.

Codigo CSS do Carousel

```
    #carousel .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 10;
}

    #carousel .text h2 {
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 1px 0;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

    #carousel .text p {
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

    #carousel .owl-dots {
    background: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.625em 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

    .owl-carousel.owl-theme .owl-dot span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 3px solid rgba(0, 40, 58, 0.57);
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0 0.3125em;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 18px;
}

    .owl-carousel.owl-theme .owl-dot.active span, .owl-carousel.owl-theme .owl-dot:hover span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #007f7f;
}
```

Comment: Pedro se possível coloque também o código HTML como aparece no navegador. Falo isso pois as vezes a estrutura das tags HTML e o CSS podem não estar batendo.

Comment: Opa está assim https://jsfiddle.net/f0yf1cws/, não carreguei o css nem js ai, mas a estrutura HTML é essa. Deixei o Index-en.html ali no Negocie online, porém se coloco link externo, da problema.

Comment: Pedro eu não vou conseguir te responder pq eu teria que ver o CSS do Owl etc. Mas o que posso te dizer é que se vc tem uma regra que é assim: `.owl-carousel.owl-theme .owl-dot span` vc vc vai e coloca um "**a**" no meio tipo assim: `.owl-carousel.owl-theme .owl-dot a span` repare que agora tem um A antes do span, isso faz a regra quebrar entendo. Acredito que deve ter um CSS que diga por exemplo `.owl img` e quando vc coloca `.owl a img` o CSS quebra entende. Acho que esse deve ser o problemas, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Opa Hugo, então não tenho nenhuma quebra nesse estilo https://jsfiddle.net/f0yf1cws/7/ O CSS é esse, porém não tem nenhum a que quebre a regra.

Comment: Então faça a regra vc rss, tipo `.owl a img {display:block !important;}` por exemplo. Acrescente a classe que se perdeu com important.

Comment: É tentei fazer isso, defini até o Owl-load no Class da Div pra testar. Mas ai ele buga tudo e carrega uma imagem de baixo da outra.

Comment: So pra atualizar, o JS responsável por carregar o caroseul é o https://jsfiddle.net/f0yf1cws/11/ mas não consegui identificar pq ele da problema e não carrega ai com link externo.